# Putting strings into vector gives empty strings

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here's part my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    FILE *in=fopen("C.in","r");
    //freopen("C.out","w",stdout);
    int maxl=0;
    int i;
    string word;
    vector<string> words;
    while(!feof(in)){
        fscanf(in,"%s ",word.c_str());
        int t=strlen(word.c_str());
        if(t>maxl){
            maxl=t;
            words.clear();
            words.insert(words.end(),word);
        }else if (t==maxl){
            words.insert(words.end(),word);
        }
    }
```

the problem occurs at

```
words.insert(words.end,word)
```

while

```
word
```

contains the word from my file, the vector item

```
words[i]
```

contains an empty string.

How is this possible?

Comment: Please show all your variable declarations!

Comment: word.c_str() returns `const char*`, so you shouldn't modify it.

Comment: [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Mike's given you the final answer, but it's probably worth pointing out that `while ( !feof( in ) )` is no better than `while ( !in.eof() )`.  Neither tell you whether the following input will succeed or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
fscanf(in,"%s ",word.c_str());
```

That's never going to work. `c_str()` is a `const` pointer to the string's current contents, which you mustn't modify. Even if you do subvert `const` (using a cast or, in this case, a nasty C-style variadic function), writing beyond the end of that memory won't change the length of the string - it will just give undefined behaviour.

Why not use C++ style I/O, reading into a `string` so that it automatically grows to the correct size?

```
std::ifstream in(filename);
std::string word;
while (in >> word) {
    if (word.size() > maxl) {
        maxl = word.size();
        words.clear();
        words.push_back(word);
    } else if (word.size() == maxl) {
        words.push_back(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: And indeed, subverting the `const` pointer yielded by `c_str()` and writing to it will yield UB even if you don't write beyond the end of the buffer.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Indeed. I'm just mentioning the part that's most likely to cause catastrophic behaviour.